# filesaver.js not working iPad Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, filesaver.js

I'm trying out Eli Grey's awesome filesaver implementation to download canvases as a PNG image.

It's working well on most platforms, but I've hit a snag on Chrome on the iPad - it just opens a new tab that remains blank.

I do have a fallback for browsers that can't handle blobs, so I'm hoping there's some feature detection I can do to recognise when I might need to use the fallback.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you found any fix for this ?